# Cannot spawn Python from node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am trying to spawn a python process from node.js as such:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const process = spawn('python', ['--version']);
```

But this throws an error:

```
$ node server2.js 
node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn python',
  path: 'python',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ]
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
const process = spawn('python', ['--version']);
```

need to be changed to:

```
const process = spawn('python3', ['--version']);
```